# Getting an type error "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str" after running below code -Kmeans Clustering in pyspark1.4.2 version

Tags: python, pyspark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-sql

`feat_cols= ['cost','mos']`-- both look like

```
| 37060.9|       186|
|23764.58|       163|
| 10000.0|         0|
| 18840.0|       142|
```

---

```
expr = [col(c).cast("Double").alias(c) for c in feat_cols]
df2 = asset_info_df1.select(*expr)`

#Create 'features' vector
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=feat_cols, outputCol="features")
df3 = assembler.transform(df2).select('features')


#Scale 'feature' so mean ~ 0 and stdev ~ 1
from pyspark.ml.feature import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler(inputCol="features", outputCol="scaledFeatures",
            withStd=True, withMean=False)
scalerModel = scaler.fit(df3)
df4 = scalerModel.transform(df3).drop('features')\
             .withColumnRenamed('scaledFeatures', 'features')

#This is the data transformation key to Kmeans
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
data5 = df4.rdd.map(lambda row: Vectors.dense([x for x in row['features']]))

clusters = KMeans.train(data5, k=3, maxIterations=10)
```

When I run the cluster [of code above I get the error of tuple indices must be integers not str. I am not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP3YK.png) able to understand the reason. Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Provide the trace of the error

Comment: @sharatpc error snapshot  is provided after clicking 2nd last line?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4572265/sharatpc can you  help ??

Comment: I don't see the trace point out the line where the tuples are being wrongly fetched. The error is Pythonic and has nothing do with Spark. Did you debug at the line where data5 is being assigned? If features in row is at index 0, try `[x for x in row[0]]`.

Comment: when i tried row[0],the error                                                                       is  "/opt/dse/dse2/resources/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/linalg.py", line 206, in __init__
    ar = np.array(ar, dtype=np.float64)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: Without an *explicit* sample of your `asset_info_df1` (is it an RDD? a dataframe?), or at least `df4` or `data5`, I doubt that anyone can be of help here...